# How to save app data in Android after app shutdown using onSaveInstanceState()?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, adb

I am trying simulate app shut down using ADB. I am storing the data in a bundle in onSaveInstanceState() so that I'm able to get the data back once I get back to the app. But I'm unable to get the data back.
Here's the code I'm using (It's from one of Google's codelabs)

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
  
    dessertTimer = DessertTimer(this.lifecycle)
    
    if(savedInstanceState != null)
    {
      
        revenue = savedInstanceState.getInt(KEY_REVENUE,0)
        dessertsSold = savedInstanceState.getInt(KEY_DESSERT_SOLD,0)
        dessertTimer.secondsCount = savedInstanceState.getInt(KEY_TIMER_SECONDS,0)
    }
  
    binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)
    binding.dessertButton.setOnClickListener {
        onDessertClicked()
    }
  
    binding.revenue = revenue
    binding.amountSold = dessertsSold
  
    binding.dessertButton.setImageResource(currentDessert.imageId)
}
```

This is the code in onSaveInstanceState()

```
 override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle?) {
   
       super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)

        outState!!.putInt(KEY_REVENUE,revenue)
        outState!!.putInt(KEY_DESSERT_SOLD,dessertsSold)
        outState!!.putInt(KEY_TIMER_SECONDS,dessertTimer.secondsCount)

}
```

Comment: Bundle's are not persistent. What you store in `onSaveInstanceState` will be lost once you close your app (it is rather used for things like configuration changes, such as when you change your devices orientation). You need other mechanisms to store persistent data. For example, you can take a look at `SharedPreferences`: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences.

Answer (score 1):

As @Beko has said, don't use `onSaveInstaceState` to save something you'll need after an app shutdown. It can not be recovered.

You have two solutions:

- Use [`SharedPreferences.Editor`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor) to store your data. `SharedPreference.Editor` can be got through [`SharedPreferences#edit`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences#edit());
- Or store the data you need to be saved in a database and fetch it later.